# how to disable complete action using dialog, so my home application will be the only home application that available to the user

Tags: android

I want to develop  an home application like in the android sample: 
[a link] 
 http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html

But not like above example I want that my home application will be the
only one, I mean that the user can not chose between my application
and the native one (an ordinary application itself).- disable the
"complete action using" dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try: the following in your HTML page:

```
<!-- Prevent the browser from opening external app handlers. -->
<meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="email=no">
```